# How to create customized Metaio POI description

Tags: android, augmented-reality, metaio, point-of-interest

I am using [metaio](http://www.metaio.com/) android sdk. (Metaio SDK 6.0.2)
I have created an app based on [TutorialLocationBasedAR](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/location-based-ar/).
How can i create some POI description (same as the picture) that appears when gemetry clicked?

[image]

Comment: I remember if you follow this http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/location-based-ar/ They have code for this!

Comment: @Fartab Can you share your sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metaio now is not a continuing project and couldn't support its users.